Vue 3.5 + TypeScriptt is possibly null error on useTemplateRef
I'm getting "value is possibly null" flags in VS Code with TypeScript in my  when I use useTemplateRef.
Of this kind:    audioPlayer.value.pause() is possibly null
Only if I add the non null assertion ! does the error go away. Yesterday the error was not there (of course, nothing has stopped working when I run the code).
Here is an example:
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref, useTemplateRef, reactive, watchPostEffect, watchEffect} from "vue";
import { PlayCircleIcon, StopCircleIcon } from "@heroicons/vue/24/solid";
import { gsap } from "gsap";

const audioPlayer = useTemplateRef("audio-player");
const seekBar = useTemplateRef("seek-bar");
const panelTrack = useTemplateRef("panel-track");
const trackIndex = ref<number>(0);
const currentTrack = ref<string>("");
const isPlaying = ref<boolean>(false);
const TRACK_WIDTH = 115;

const playlist = reactive([
    { artist: "Direct", song: "Direct - Abandon.mp3" },
    { artist: "Kubix", song: "Kubix - Run Away.mp3" }
])

const togglePlay = () => {
    isPlaying.value = !isPlaying.value;
    if (isPlaying.value) {
        audioPlayer.value.play();
    } else {
        audioPlayer.value.pause();
    }
    audioPlayer.value!.play();
}

Only audioPlayer.value!.play(); with non null assertion leaves no error. But cannot figure out why I did not see this yesterday, and it's not good to write ! everywhere...
THE HTML bit for this element is:
 <audio ref="audio-player" preload="metadata" v-on:loadedmetadata="setDurMaxForSeek"
        v-on:timeupdate="trackDurForSeek" v-on:ended="checkTrackIndex">
        <source :src="`@/assets/audio/${currentTrack}`" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

EDIT:
Of course if I write     if (audioPlayer.value) audioPlayer.value.play(); then the error highlight is gone in VSCode. But the mystery is what changed overnight in my setup...
Thanks, T

I think it makes more sense for the error to exist than for it to not.  Preventing runtime errors is one of the advantages of using a strongly typed language like TypeScript.  It requires you to check that nullable objects are not null before you use them, and template refs are nullable.

Yes, I'm keeping TS in strict mode from now on. As they say on Vue: Note that for strict type safety, it is necessary to use optional chaining or type guards when accessing el.value. This is because the initial ref value is null until the component is mounted, and it can also be set to null if the referenced element is unmounted by v-if.
